# How to train tensorflow model on ubuntu?

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a tensorflow model on an Ubuntu 16.4 machine. However, TF consumes pretty much all of the available RAM soon after the training commences (8GB), and is killed by an OOM reaper. If I disable the OOM killer, it terminates with a segmentation fault instead.

My search has so far not turned out anything that would indicate you can limit the amount of RAM tensorflow uses, only GPU related parameters are configurable, but that won't solve the issue. If I use ulimit linux command to limit the RAM of the python process to say 4GB, the script is stuck forever and does not even start - it's almost as if it never even started executing what is in main method of the script.

I have scoured many tutorials online precisely on this topic, and nobody ever seems to run into this problem. My question is - how do people actually do it? Clearly I am missing something. This problem does not manifest itself on Windows, training completes, but is excruciatingly slow.

EDIT: The problematic function is this one:

```
def finetune():
    upper_model = Sequential()
    upper_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=core_model.output_shape[1:]))
    upper_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    upper_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    upper_model.add(Dense(len(class_indices), activation='sigmoid'))
    upper_model.load_weights(top_model_weights_filename)

    final_model = Model(inputs=core_model.input, outputs=upper_model(core_model.output))

    for layer in final_model.layers[:15]:
        layer.trainable = False

    final_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                        # optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-6, momentum=0.9),
                        optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-5),
                        metrics=['accuracy'])

    if not Path(final_model_weights_filename).is_file():
        print("Final weights not found, calculating anew.")

        data_augmentation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
            rotation_range=40,
            width_shift_range=0.2,
            height_shift_range=0.2,
            shear_range=0.2,
            zoom_range=0.2,
            horizontal_flip=True,
            fill_mode='nearest')
        data_augmentation_datagen.mean = normalization_datagen.mean
        data_augmentation_datagen.std = normalization_datagen.std

        val_loss_checkpoints = []
        weights_checkpoints = []

        for e in range(epochs):
            print("-" * 100)
            print("Epoch %d" % (e + 1))
            print("-" * 100)

            for i, (x_train, y_train) in enumerate(iterate_dataset('train', converted_images_dir)):
                print('Iterating over training batch number %d at %s' % (i + 1, str(datetime.now().time())))
                train_iterator = data_augmentation_datagen.flow(
                    x_train, y_train,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    shuffle=False)

                steps = x_train.shape[0] // batch_size
                if x_train.shape[0] % batch_size != 0:
                    steps += 1

                final_model.fit_generator(train_iterator, steps)

            loss = []

            for i, (x_valid, y_valid) in enumerate(iterate_dataset('valid', converted_images_dir)):
                print('Iterating over validation batch number %d' % (i + 1))
                valid_iterator = normalization_datagen.flow(
                    x_valid, y_valid,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    shuffle=False)

                steps = x_valid.shape[0] // batch_size
                if x_valid.shape[0] % batch_size != 0:
                    steps += 1

                batch_loss = final_model.evaluate_generator(valid_iterator, steps)
                loss.append(batch_loss)

            epoch_loss = np.array(loss).mean(axis=0)[0]
            epoch_acc = np.array(loss).mean(axis=0)[1]
            print('Loss after epoch %d is %.2f' % (e + 1, epoch_loss))
            print('Accuracy after epoch %d is %.2f' % (e + 1, epoch_acc))
            print()


        final_model.save_weights(final_model_weights_filename)

    else:
        print("Reusing found final weights.")
        final_model.load_weights(final_model_weights_filename)

    return final_model
```

I can provide additional explanation if necessary.

Comment: The RAM usage is directly linked to the size of your model and the size of the batches you train on. Set you batch size to 1 and check if it still goes OOM (in which case, your model is too big). If it doesn't, start increasing the batch size until you find the biggest value for which training works.

Comment: I ran some basic numbers, and it should work just fine. I use VGG16 without the FC layers, I replaced those by a single 256 FC layer with a 14-class final classification layer. My network has 21M parameters instead of 138M, which is roughly 80MB of memory. I use a batch size of 10, and for a forward and backward pass I should need about 200M per image. That adds up to 2000 + 80MB, which still doesn't explain why it won't work on 8GB RAM.

Comment: Then you have a bug in your code, in which case you'll need to post it in your question

Comment: Uploaded the relevant part of the code.

Comment: I tried the code with a batch number of 2, and after almost 24 hours, the process still runs. The process claimed about 75% of the total memory, but how can this be? Clearly my calculations were naive and there just has to be something else consuming much more than meets the eye.